# Intercept http request in Angular before getting authenticate popup

Tags: angular, http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to find a way to avoid the authenticate popup when I got a 401 error code + Basic Authenticate.

Unfortunately, I can't make changes in the server so I'm implementing a http interceptor - to redirect to login page - before getting the popup.

I have find help of a blog post but can't make it work. It doesn't matter if the login is wrong or right, I end up in the page : /loginPage?login=loginITypedIn&password=pwdITypedIn

export class HttpService {

```
constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) { }

get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(this.http.get(url,options));
}

intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable.catch((err, source) => {
        if(err.status == 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/loginPage'], { queryParams: {} });
            return Observable.empty();
        } else {
           return Observable.throw(err);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And calling it in another service :

```
return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
                .map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

I apologize for my english but I'm totally stuck.

Comment: You get the popup when you try to open a page. How would an interceptor help?

Comment: I get a popup when I type in wrong login/password.